# Read Event log file from path

Tags: c#, windows, logging, event-log

My question is very similar to this one [How do you open the event log programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609533/how-do-you-open-the-event-log-programatically) 
Except i'm logging anything. I need to create db of Log Entries from multiple unconnected machines. I get .evtx files then i try to process them. Right now i'm doing it from exported xml files. But i would like to skip the to xml conversion part.  I've read the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.EventLog.aspx article but i didn't find what i was looking for. Is there a way to do what i want without converting to xml?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var reader = new EventLogReader(@"path\to\log.evtx", PathType.FilePath))
{
    EventRecord record;
    while((record = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
    {
        using (record)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}: {2}", record.TimeCreated, record.LevelDisplayName, record.FormatDescription());
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: This definitely solves the problem. Thanks!
Since [EventRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventrecord(v=vs.110).aspx)  implements IDisposable shouldn't it be wraped in using ?

Comment: @PonuryCiastkarz I didn't notice that. I just assumed it was just a simple container for the data. Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm getting 'EventLogReader' is inaccessible due to its protection level, with EventLogReader.ReadEvent() having the same error on both .Net Standard and .Net Core frameworks. I'm thinking these have become deprecated since this Answer was written.

Comment: @computercarguy This class wasn't included with .NET Standard. You have to use either full .NET  framework or [.NET Core 3](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31358). That error seems to be from an unrelated package (TaskScheduler) that is suggested by Visual Studio.