# How to read external event log file using EventLog class

Tags: c#, event-log

I can read the application portion of my system's event log programmatically just fine this way:

```
EventLog aLog;
aLog = new EventLog("Application", ".");
```

The event entries can then be looked up in aLog.Entries which are of the class EventLogEntryCollection.

Now, let's say instead of the default system log I want to read another events log file imported from another system (such as one called externLog.evtx) .  But I'm not sure how to pass externLog.evtx (and its absolute path) to EventLog creation call.  For instance, this call fails:

```
 aLog = new EventLog("c:\\temp\\externLog.evtx", "Application", ".");
```

I have seen suggestions for doing this such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809133/read-event-log-file-from-path) which does this:

```
Use System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader:

using (var reader = new EventLogReader(@"path\to\log.evtx", PathType.FilePath)){
EventRecord record;
while((record = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
{
    using (record)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}: {2}", record.TimeCreated, record.LevelDisplayName, record.FormatDescription());
    }
}
```

}

But this is reading the events into objects of EventRecord class. Is there a way to read these external files into objects of EventLog class, or EventLogEntry or EventLogEntriesCollections?

Comment: You can cast `reader.ReadEvent()` to `EventLogRecord`. Not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for your input but, no, that's not what I wanted.  I know EventLogReader is returning an object that is of EventRecord type.  I said I want EventLog, not EventRecord.  I doubt I can use EventLogReader for that purpose. I only showed the EventLogReader example to acknowledge there are ways for reading an external event log file, such as that one, but I'm looking for a way that provides the entries in an EventLog class, not other classes.  Did that make it clear?