# What is even ID when there is uploaded file in FTP IIS 8

Tags: scripting, ftp, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I need an Event ID when there is someone who uploads file in my "FTP Server on IIS 8" so I can run a PowerShell script.

I have multiple remote sites that are sending files every time and I want to save automatically the data that they are uploading in my database I already created the program on it and its working but I can't add the PowerShell script in task scheduler because I don't know when it will be triggered.

Can someone help me to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think what you need is this to start with - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349251(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: but how can i see it in event viewer?

Comment: If you are running ftp over IIS, check under :
Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\

var log = EventLog.GetEventLogs().Where(x => x == "Application").First();
foreach (var entry in log.Entries) {
  // Do something with the entry
}

--Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609533/how-do-you-open-the-event-log-programatically